# VBA DoCmd.TransferSharePointList Not Linking

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 tool that I created that links to some SharePoint lists. This solution was working fine until my end users decided they needed more People/Group fields which put us over the view threshold for lookups. I do not have access to central administration so this is a hard stop. So I decided that I could link to three views and join the data with a query and all should be good. To be able to link to a SharePoint list view you have to use DoCmd.TransferSharePointList instead of using the External Data option. External Data links to the entire table thus the threshold prevents data from being returned.

I need to link to three views so my code is:

```
 Function SPVLink()

DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, "http://server/sites/sitename/", "{94E4E5D3-77C8-4170-BBA2-3F9533C24627}", "{CF2A3189-B45B-4527-A4F3-CF323C9E7E21}", "IssueTracker0", True
DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, "http://server/sites/sitename/", "{94E4E5D3-77C8-4170-BBA2-3F9533C24627}", "{C6C7ABBA-C159-400F-8402-F6B56954BA5C}", "IssueTracker1", True
DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, "http://server/sites/sitename/", "{94E4E5D3-77C8-4170-BBA2-3F9533C24627}", "{290947AD-8BC4-4610-82C1-E636CFBBF06C}", "IssueTracker2", False

 End Function
```

This runs without error however the linked views are not created. I also tried running this as a Macro and the result is the same in that it runs with no error yet no links are created. I did some searching but didn't find this kind of issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoCmd.TransferSharePointList in VBA will not let you link to multiple views.

**acLinkSharePointList** will link to the entire list like External Data does.

**acImportSharePointList** will let you import only the data displayed in the associated view.

Because the database was already linked to the lists it would not create new links with different names.